# listing text files names in a new text file for reading links. getting desire result in print command but trying to save it in file or in list nope

Tags: python

i was trying to extract links from many text files for that i tried to make a name list of text files in separate file to store this names in list . but when i tried to get output as print it give me my desire output but when tried to store it in list or a new file it is showing encoded or not readable format .
i marked my desire output in green and undesired output in redcircle.
Can you guide me to achieve my output according to desire
[image]

```
   docs = []
    with open('files.txt','r') as f:
       content = f.readlines()
       for doc in content:
          if '-' in doc:
             print(doc[101:])
             docs.append(doc[101:])

        #print(doc[101:])
        
        #print(type(doc))
    print(docs)
```

Comment: what is the content of files.txt? seems like the data is encoded

Answer (score 0):

This snippet might help you in fetching file names from the txt file

```
docs = []
with open('files.txt', 'r') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    for doc in content:
        file_name = doc.rstrip().split(" ")[-1]
        docs.append(file_name)
print(docs)
```